# Error while adding attributes

Tags: tcl

while trying to add new new attribute I am getting

```
Error: #1900068: add attribute failed
Error: #1900003: Expected keyword - got 'the'
```

Here is my code

```
add attribute LabelTest
 description “Enter the shipping label number” 
 type integer;
```

Comment: your quotes (") seem nonstandard. `“` vs. `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl (in common with many other programming languages) requires that you use a real `"` instead of ‘smart quotes’ like `“` and `”`. If your editor insists on changing `"` to `“` when you press <kbd>"</kbd>, you are *strongly* advised to use a different editor. There are many editors suitable for the task, but they are disjoint from word processors.

Since `“` is not a special character to Tcl at all, `“Enter` is just a “bareword” with six characters in it, which Tcl is perfectly happy with. (It's followed by a `the` word, a `shipping` word, etc.) However, the `description` command is not! It wants just one argument, and that means you need to use the right type of quote.

```
add attribute LabelTest
description "Enter the shipping label number"
type integer;
```

Notice that Stack Overflow is highlighting my corrected version differently to your code. This is because it uses the right type of quote…